# WordPress page link goes very wrong

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a theme that would have essentially 2 pages, one would be a workshop, and the other would be an art page.

- The main page for the domain has `header()`, `footer()` the content file is named `front-page.php` where I noticed that WordPress disregards the "Reading settings" of "Your homepage displays" ( Your latest posts / A static page )
- I've created `art-page.php` to include new headers and footers for art (`header('art')`, `footer('art')`)
- I followed the WordPress Codex of creating a new page, so art is a page I've published, seen that it's ID is 1742, I created the home page link to art as: `<a href="<?php echo get_page_link(1742); ?>"><div id="art-link"></div></a>`

### Result:

When pressing on that link, it loads `/the-art` with a 200 response, including all the css and js for it, yet it loads the home page **and under the footer of the home page it creates another home page** with the header, then in the content a row with "art" (the name of the page) following by the main footer.

### Expected result:

From the home page, click on the art link from above, wordpress will load art page (`art-page.php`) as a whole new page.

### `art-page.php`

```
get_header('art');
?>
</div>
<h1>test art</h1>
<?php
get_footer('art');
?>
```

I'm a programmer with a basic grasp of the wordpress, yet struggling to create the expected result above.

Thanks,

Bud

Answer (score -1):

I now study how to make a theme in wordpress.

First you need an Index.php file and a style.css file (these two files are the minimun)

You can cut the upper part of index.php and create the header.php an the down portion and create the footer.php.

You can have a static page as 1st page and the filename can be front-page.php and another page for blog.

BUT if you want to see a set of archives you use archive.php (post in same category, or of the same author e.t.c)

IF you want to see a post (one) you use the  single.php or page.php for a single page.

In wordpres we have pages (static content like About us) and post this can written new info from author.

If you have difficulty, read a givem default theme, or use a starter theme and convert it to what you want.

Some starter themes to use are:

https://underscores.me/  (from  authors of wp)

http://jointswp.com/    (Freamework foundation)

https://understrap.com/  (Bootstrap 4)

Before to start read about theme hierachy in wordpress
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

example themes

https://medium.com/pixelperfecthtml/step-by-step-guide-to-convert-html-template-to-wordpress-theme-8d89264eb4be

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites

Comment: Elias, thanks for the time invested, I've already been to the wordpress codex and read and know what you wrote above, but your answer has really no correlation to my question.

Comment: I  was trying to say to you how to learn to do a theme in wp because you did not know, i think all the staff , and me also I  learn